# PHP Error: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver

Tags: php, email

Could anyone please help me with the problem I am currently having, when users try to register it allows them to register, however when I try to register users they don't get an confirmation email sent to their email as I am getting a error which says that mail(); failed to connect to mail-server., please help or advise.

I have downloaded phpmailer however how can I implement this in my register and login system form, I am getting the below error. I am running this on localhost wamp server.

```
Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &amp;quot;localhost&amp;quot; port 25, verify your &amp;quot;SMTP&amp;quot; and &amp;quot;smtp_port&amp;quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set()
```

php.ini File Layout

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25
; auth_username = bradvisor15@gmail.com
; auth_password = password

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = you@yourdomain
```

When I test phpmailer with a test example below it works.

```
<?php

require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'bradvisor15@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'password';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

$mail->From = 'bradvisor15@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'BradVisor';
$mail->addAddress('safyannawaz@hotmail.com', 'Anil Nawaz');

$mail->addReplyTo('haleema73@hotmail.co.uk', 'Anil Nawaz');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer';
$mail->Body    = 'Hi, Test email';

if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';

?>
```

Comment: first try with simple mail() function , if it sends mail than try phpmailer

Comment: The problem implied by that error message is that you *don't have* a mail daemon installed/running.

Comment: Are you running this on a live webhost or your test / dev webserver?

Comment: Simple mail function does send, I have sent mail using phpmailer however I cannot implement it in my project.

Comment: I am running this on localhost, wamp server.